# jQuery get context?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having this code :

```
 $(".toggle", '.Div1').on('click',function () 
  {
   alert("I was clicked becuase im .toggle is under the context of _________");
  });
```

I need to get the context which the `$(this)` value is under.

How can I get the value of  `_______` ?

Comment: I thought `context()` would do this for you, but it appears to be the context of the selected element: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/mHszf/

Comment: As an aside, why would you need this? If you're specifying a context, then you must already know what it is?

Comment: `$("#toggle", '#Div1')` makes no sense. `$("#Div1 #toggle")` would make some sense but really, `$('#toggle')` should do the job unless that element can be at different positions in your DOM tree.

Comment: As jQuery provides only the element, I don't think it's possible to get the context of the jQuery object on which the handler was bound.

Comment: @ThiefMaster correct. but it doesnt really matter  , it could be class and not id. I just want to know if i can get the context. ( changed  and edit in my question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible. The Event object does not contain any reference to the jQuery object used to bind it.